# AWS connection timeout when running Spark job on EMR

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, emr

I'm trying to submit a simple spark job in an Amazon EMR cluster. My cluster has 5 M4.2xlarge instances (1 master, 4 slaves), each with 16 vCPU, and 32 gigs of memory.

This is my code:

```
def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
 val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
  .set("hive.s3.max-client-retries", "50")
  .set("hive.s3.max-error-retries", "50")
  .set("hive.s3.max-connections", "100")
  .set("hive.s3.connect-timeout", "5m")
  .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
  .set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.VertexAttributeBlock")
  .set("spark.broadcast.compress", "true")

 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Spark Hive Example")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config(sparkConfig)
    .getOrCreate()

// Set Kryo for serializing
GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses(sparkConfig)
val res = spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 limit 10000")
val edgesRDD = res.rdd.map(row => Edge(row.getString(0).hashCode, row.getString(1).hashCode, row(2).asInstanceOf[String]))

val res_two = spark.sql("SELECT col1 FROM table2 where col1 is not NULL and col1 != '' limit 100000")
val vertexRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = res_two.rdd.map(row => (row.getString(0).hashCode, row(0).asInstanceOf[String]))

val graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgesRDD)

val connectedComponents = graph.connectedComponents().vertices
```

Both table1, and table2 are S3 backed external tables on hive. When I run this program, my job fails with the following error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 827 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 827.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 921, xxx.internal, executor 3): com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1069)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4169)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4116)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1237)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:24)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:10)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:82)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:176)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:94)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AbstractAmazonS3Lite.getObjectMetadata(AbstractAmazonS3Lite.java:39)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:768)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.open(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:773)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.extractMetaInfoFromFooter(ReaderImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:286)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy37.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1190)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    ... 59 more
```

Not sure if it is coming from hadoop or when reading from hive, but I saw a similar issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/7V5gDfzbmmk), so I added the following params in my spark-submit command:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize=1000 -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout=60" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize=1000 -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout=60"
```

Still doesn't work. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue, and I wonder if it is a bug.

Comment: Nope, still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem, did you find out a solution or workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

TLDR: The property you need to set is **fs.s3.maxConnections** in the **emrfs-site.xml** configuration file. It defaults to 50. We were getting exactly the same error/stack trace as you, so I set it to 5000, which fixed the problem and had no ill effects.

From what I can tell, the root cause is InputFormat implementations that do not properly use try...finally to ensure that connections get closed when an exceptions are thrown. Notably, older versions of Hive, including v1.2.1 that Spark is compiled against, exhibit this bug. Hive 2.x massively refactors OrcInputFormat, though I haven't verified that the bug is fixed, nor do I know if/when/how you can compile Spark against Hive 2.x.

The workaround increases the size of the connection pool, as suggested in another answer, but both the property and its location are quite different than in the "classic" S3 filesystems (s3/s3a/s3n). Of course, this isn't documented anywhere and required decompilation of the emrfs jar to tease out...

Comment: Interesting. what's the Hadoop JIRA ID for that bug?

Comment: There's [HIVE-13216](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13216), which describes the missing try...finally issue, apparently fixed in 2.1.0. There's also [this issue in spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/156) which causes a similar problem, again because S3 filesystem connections aren't being closed properly. I should be more specific that this is my leading candidate root cause, but haven't tracked it down 100%. It may be that Hive tries to open more than 50 files at once for some reason. In our case, the workaround works with no adverse effects.

Comment: To add to the above, I've experienced with with EMR 5.9.0 and 5.10.0. the issue seems to be connector specific. I'm using Parquet format and still facing the issue. However a legacy job on EMR4.8.0 has no issues with this.

Comment: Any alternate solutions to this?  I eventually was setting `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum=1000000` and still getting the error.

Comment: Is there a way to set this without having to modify the emrfs-site.xml file in every node?  This is a horrible mess to automate.

Comment: @JonathanTraupman Thank you! So I've set fs.s3.maxConnections to 250 since I am reading 200 parquet file but still get the Error, this is because some connections are left open even after failed to read parquet file, correct? I've thought increasing maxConnection to very large number would be a fix however from user4601931 , it doesn't seem so. Any updates or references relating to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use EMRFS, but I do know the other spark/hadoop S3 clients all use a pool of http connections for their requests to S3, and "timeout waiting for pool" messages invariably means "pool isn't big enough". See if you can find out what the emrfs options are for increasing that pool size. You will need at least one for every worker thread running in your process, and I'd double it in the hope that emrfs parallelises block uploads the way the s3a client does.

Comment: Interesting, I am running in to this issue for the first time as well with emrfs. Wonder if it is a bug because I see no documentation for the emrfs max.connection pool.

Comment: you'll have to take it with the AWS EMR team. I only deal unpaid with support issues related to S3A "file @ JIRA with a patch" & paid for Hortonworks HDP "that's interesting, lets see if I can fix it"